# Dependency Injection in Transient Objects

Tags: c#, unit-testing, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern

I'd like some advice on how to structure some objects via dependency injection.

Most of my application is singletons, and it's pretty straightforward to inject singletons as dependencies of each other.

However, I have a situation where I dynamically generate some transient objects that depend on several singletons.

Here's some C# pseudocode of the current situation:

```
// random singletons
public static class SingletonA {...}
public static class SingletonB {...}
public static class SingletonC {...}

// random objects that all need to depend on some subset of the above singletons
public class BaseTask {...}
public class TaskA : BaseTask {...}
public class TaskB : BaseTask {...}
public class TaskC : BaseTask {...}

public class Scheduler {
    public Scheduler() {
    }

    public void Start() {
        // When these tasks are created is actually really dependent on business logic,
        // and each task executes a bunch of internal logic.
        // Each Task can create more children Task at arbitrary times too.
        ...
        var taskA = new TaskA();
        ...
        var taskB = new TaskB();
        ...
        var taskC = new TaskC();
        ...
}
```

There is code in all of `TaskA`, `TaskB`, `TaskC`, ... that calls methods on the singletons. Also, each task can construct new tasks.

If I use dependency injection, I could do something like:

```
public class Scheduler {
    private ISingletonA _singletonA;
    private ISingletonB _singletonB;
    ...

    public Scheduler(ISingletonA singletonA, ISingletonB singletonB, ...) {
        _singletonA = singletonA;
        _singletonB = singletonB;
        ...
    }

    public void Start() {
        ...
        var taskA = new TaskA(_singletonA, _singletonB, ...);
        ...
        var taskB = new TaskB(_singletonA, _singletonB, ...);
        ...
        var taskC = new TaskC(_singletonA, _singletonB, ...);
        ...
    }
}
```

This seems like a mess, so I was thinking of refactoring all of the `TaskA`, `TaskB`, `TaskC` into a common class and making something like a factory:

```
public class Scheduler {
    public TaskFactory _taskFactory

    public Scheduler(TaskFactory taskFactory) {
        _taskFactory = taskFactory;
    }

    public void Start() {
        ...
        var taskA = _taskFactory.NewTaskA(_taskFactory);
        ...
        var taskB = _taskFactory.NewTaskB(_taskFactory);
        ...
        var taskC = _taskFactory.NewTaskC(_taskFactory);
        ...
    }
}
```

Any better ideas? And if not, I don't think this is the factory pattern. Is there a more accurate name?

Comment: You show your singletons as static classes. Was that intentional?

Comment: Yes, using a factory pattern is the first and most obvious option to handle the case where transient objects need injected dependencies. The factory is responsible for instantiating and populating the constructor arguments, which it can do simply by copying its own injected dependencies into constructor arguments. Just be sure to give the factory an interface so that unit tests can stub it.

Comment: @Nkosi They are currently static classes. When I introduce dependency injection, they will not be static classes.

Comment: @JohnWu I thought factories usually have one create method to create a variety of objects. In my case, my factory interface will have 3+ creates (basically collating all the constructors into a single class).

Is that still considered a "Factory"?

The unfortunate thing is that I'm going to need to pass the factory as a dependency into each of the `Task` classes as well.

Comment: @JohnWu I'm talking about `Factory` in a semantic sense.

Comment: @user881185 I wrote an answer to demonstrate how to do this with a more legitimate factory class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define a factory class whose sole purpose is to construct your `TaskX` objects, including containing all the dependencies:

```
class MyTaskFactory : IMyTaskFactory
{
    private readonly ISingletonA _singletonA;
    private readonly ISingletonB _singletonB;

    public MyTaskFactory(ISingletonA singletonA, ISingletonB singletonB)
    {
        _singletonA = singletonA;
        _singletonB = singletonB;
    }

    public T Resolve<T>() where T : ITask
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(TaskA)) return (T)(object)GetTaskA();
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(TaskB)) return (T)(object)GetTaskB();
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(TaskC)) return (T)(object)GetTaskC();

        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Type not supported: {0}", typeof(T).FullName));
    }

    protected TaskA GetTaskA()
    {
        return new TaskA(_singletonA);
    }

    protected TaskB GetTaskB()
    {
        return new TaskB(_singletonA, _singletonB);
    }

    protected TaskC GetTaskC()
    {
        return new TaskC(_singletonA, "Other runtime parameter");
    }
}

public class Scheduler
{
    protected readonly IMyTaskFactory _taskFactory;

    public Scheduler(IMyTaskFactory taskFactory)
    {
        _taskFactory = taskFactory;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var taskA = _taskFactory.Resolve<TaskA>();
        var taskB = _taskFactory.Resolve<TaskB>();
        var taskC = _taskFactory.Resolve<TaskC>();
    }
}
```

You then add the factory to your composition root:

```
container.Register<IMyTaskFactory,MyTaskFactory>();
```

And the dependencies will show up where they are needed.

Click [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nbV63V) for a Fiddle containing compilable code.

Comment: My instantiation of tasks is actually even more complicated. Each task depends on a varying set of singletons as well as primitives (like strings, ints, etc.) So the various constructors are quite different and hard to generalize.

In this case, it seems better to just "violate" the traditional "factory" pattern and have multiple creation methods in the factory. Is there a name for this style?

Comment: Bear in mind that unit testers will have to mock this, and it's easier for them to write a single mock `Resolve<T>` statement. But you don't have to do it that way for it to be a factory. I don't know of any special name for it when you have separate methods for the different types.

Comment: I agree with your point that unit testers will have to mock it, but given the variance in constructor parameters, it seems too difficult to cram them into one generic method. How would you suggest achieving that?

Comment: I tend to agree. if the logic isn't generic, a generic method isn't appropriate. You can use separate methods. You could also implement both with a simple (although silly-looking) series of `if` statements, if you want (see my updated example).

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably go with separate methods, and also pass along the factory into each `Task` since a `Task` can instantiate a child `Task` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think what you did is something similar to the Abstract Factory pattern.

I'm not sure as to how deep you want your application to be configurable. What I suggest with your current structure and based on what you showed is to create an application file where you can mix and match the injections.

```js
    {
        "Schedulers": [
            {
                "id": "A",
                "type": "....",
                "tasks": "tA, tB"
            },
            {
                "id": "B",
                "type": "....",
                "tasks": "tC"
            }
        ],
        "Tasks": [
            {
                "id": "tA",
                "type": "..."
            },
            {
                "id": "tB",
                "type": "..."
            },
            {
                "id": "tC",
                "type": "..."
            }
        ]
    }
```

The basic idea is that you can assign "tasks" to your "schedulers".

However, in order to do this one, you need to use another IoC container such as Autofac since the default ASP.NET Core DI container makes this somewhat impossible to achieve.